# What do Japanese say when they call their pet cats/dogs?

Tags: spoken-language

We sometimes say in English,

> Hey kitty come over here.

Do they say,

> **Cat**Chan iku yo...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We call our pets by their (nick)names most of the time.

> [ *The pet's name* (+ *chan* to show extra affection)］、 こっちおいで。([...], kocchi oide.)

You can replace the name with  generic terms like 猫ちゃん(neko-chan; *kitty*) and ワンちゃん(wan-chan; *doggy*) if you don't know what they are called.

行くよ(iku yo) means "let's go", by the way.

Comment: That's a great answer plus some new learning. arigato.